# Error getting value of input text :null

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have a page with an input text I want to display its value but it always shows null.

Here is the code

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
UIViewRoot root = context.getViewRoot();
RichInputText inputText = (RichInputText) root.findComponent("it1");
String   myParam = (String)inputText.getValue();
system.out.println("Input field content:" + myParam);
```

Input field content: null

Comment: Your code looks fine,but have you checked whether the id is "it1" really?

Answer (score 0):

The question is when, where on on which action you execute the code you showed here. Are you sure that the value you have put into this field with the id it1 is already submitted when you execute the code?

Show us the definition of the field on the page, please!

And mention your jdev version, pelase!